# Насколько эстетично не ставить некоторые {} в C++ коде?

Tags: c++, оформление

Я начинаю изучать C++. По ходу изучения, заметил определенную вещь, а именно возможность не ставить *фигурные скобки* (`{}`) для ограничения например, тела цикла, ветвления и т.д. При этом, во время компиляции, никаких проблем нет и код без фигурных скобок работает так же правильно, как и код с ними.

Хотелось бы узнать, насколько это правильно с точки зрения эстетичности кода и какой вариант использовать и есть ли вообще хоть какая-то разница.

Для примера приведу код с *фигурными скобками*:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Hello, world" << endl;
    }

}
```

Без *фигурных скобок*:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    while (true)
        cout << "Hello, world" << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ставить или не ставить скобки - ни разу не вопрос эстетичности или удобства. Возможность в некоторых ситуациях опускать фигурные скобки, как и другие компактифицирующие конструкции, была заложена в язык с определенной целью - сократить объем файлов с кодом. Это было очень актуально в 70-е и 80-е и способствовало широкому распространению С, а затем и С++, но сейчас является скорее атавизмом.

Проблемы обычно начинаются c посыла *"никаких проблем нет и код без фигурных скобок работает так же правильно, как и код с ними"*.

1. выражение в теле цикла или ветвления может внезапно оказаться макросом:

```
#define gl_produce(ind, h) ktr_produce2(ind, h); if (0 != ktr_error()) { return -1; }
...
while (count--)
    gl_produce(count, h);
```

2. даже когда внутри ветвления действительно только одно выражение, опускание скобок может приводить к внезапному изменению принадлежности блоков:

```
if (condition)
   do_something();
else
   do_something_else();

// добавляется еще одно внутреннее условие
if (condition)
   if (new_condition)
       do_something();
else // теперь относится к if (new_condition)
   do_something_else();
```

3. хотя конструкции `case` формально вообще не содержат скобок, как часть, однако их наличие или отсутствие напрямую влияет на работоспособность таких блоков:

```
switch(num)
{
    case 1:
        ::std::string sdf{};
        ::std::cout << sdf;
        break;
    case 2: // ошибка, пропуск инициализации sdf
        ::std::cout << "hello";
        break;
}
```

Comment: Все бы ничего, но вы приводите примеры, когда без скобок - просто ошибка, которую не пропустит компилятор, и в этом случае вопрос просто не может встать. А вопрос *изначально* был о том, ставить или нет там, где и так, и так - правильно.

Comment: Именно, вопрос был именно такой. Но все равно, очень благодарен за ваш ответ.

Comment: @Harry *"когда без скобок - просто ошибка, которую не пропустит компилятор"* -  в примерах 1 и 2 никакой ошибки нет, в примере 3 - в зависимости от компилятора, некоторые могут только предупредить.

Comment: @h4cktivist Товарищъ Harry вводит вас в заблуждение.  В примерах 1 и 2 правильно и так и так, а в случае с 3 некоторые компиляторы протестовать не будут.

Comment: @user7860670 Спасибо вам обоим, буду иметь ввиду все ваши советы и ответы :)

Answer (score 10):

Вопрос скорее не эстетики. Если в команде принято так или эдак - делайте, как в команде. Если работаете в одиночку - как вам удобно. Но учтите, что без скобки потом, впопыхах, вы можете добавить еще одну строчку и забыть о скобках. И хорошо, если это будет что-то типа

```
if (a > b)
    cout << "OK";
else 
    cout << "Fail";
```

превратившееся в

```
if (a > b)
    с = a - b;
    cout << "OK";
else 
    cout << "Fail";
```

где компилятор выручит... А если

```
while (true)
    cout << "Hello, world" << endl;
```

превратится в

```
while (true)
    n++;
    cout << "Hello, world" << endl;
```

Тогда как? Поэтому я бы *рекомендовал* (не навязывая :)) как начинающему ставить скобки, просто для своего же спокойствия.

Со временем вы решите сами, как вам удобнее.

И еще раз - работая в команде с выработанным стилем кодирования - придерживайтесь стиля команды.

Comment: Понял, спасибо :)